# UnitTest時にWarningが出たので出ないように対処したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rubyを始めたばかりです．
以下のようなwarningが出たのですが，これは全く問題が無いwarningなのでしょうか？
できれば，このwarningを解消したいです．

ご教授宜しくお願いします．

```
/Users/ishii/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/CMath.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant CMath::RealMath
/Users/ishii/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/cmath.rb:28: warning: previous definition of RealMath was here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「`CMath.rb` の28行目で定義しようとしている `CMath::RealMath` が、既に `cmath.rb` の28行目で定義されている」という意味のwarningです。

普通にインストールしたら `CMath.rb` というファイルは無いと思うので、何か特殊なことをしたのではないでしょうか。
行番号が同じなので、`cmath.rb` と `CMath.rb` が同じファイルなのかもしれません。

Comment: なぜか，`require 'cmath'` をしているつもりが `require 'CMath'` をしているファイルがあり，訂正したら解消しました．ありがとうございました．